# Telegram example of how to use CURL for windows 10 to message myself with a bot

Tags: windows, curl, telegram, command-prompt, telegram-bot

I found the following curl example to use a telegram bot to message a user. But that is written in PHP.

Is there an example of how to use the curl command in windows 10 command prompt to send a message to myself in telegram messenger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those who landed here due to above method is not working anymore -> you can use curl POST request like the following:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"chat_id\": \"-100XXXXXXXXXX\", \"text\": \"test_message\", \"disable_notification\": false}" https://api.telegram.org/bot{API_TOKEN}/sendMessage
```

Where

- **-s** - Silent mode,
- **-o /dev/null** - redirect result output to nowhere, in case where the command is not working remove the argument to find possible cause,
- **disable_notification: false** - send the message silently without telegram notification.

For those who really likes .bat/.sh scripts there is an option to put the command into a .bat/.sh script, replace **test_message** with **%~1**/**$1** placeholders respectively and execute the script with message argument like:

```
. ./sendMessage.sh "Specific message having spaces"
```

or

```
. ./sendMessage.sh singleWordWithoutSpaces
```

Comment: both techniques still work

Answer (score 3):

You haven't mentioned the PHP code, but using CURL you can simply call:

```
curl https://api.telegram.org/bot123456:ABC-DEF1234ghIkl-zyx57W2v1u123ew11/sendMessage?chat_id=1234&text=hi
```

Replace `123456:ABC-DEF1234ghIkl-zyx57W2v1u123ew11` with your own bot token and 1234 with your id. Don't forget to start the bot before messaging yourself.

Comment: It will be amazing to tel us know how to find the bot token and my ID, because I am using some ID's from which I get this error   "error_code": 404,

Comment: @Dimitar You get a bot token when you create a new bot by messaging botfather username on Telegram. As for your user_id you can get it by messaging https://t.me/userinfobot

Comment: Leaving this here for completeness:

I got 404 because I forgot to prefix the bot token with `bot` (`12345:t0-ke-n` -> `bot12345:t0-ke-n`). If anyone reading this is facing the same issue, double check that.